# PHP object array in an IF statement

Tags: php, arrays, object, if-statement, count

I have the following code:

```
<?php if($count >= 10){ 
    do this
}?>
```

Using this code:

```
<?php print_r($count); ?>
```

I see the contents of $count as

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [COUNT(*)] => 12 ) )
```

Question is: How do I get the 12 in the object array to be used in my IF statement?

Comment: I'm not sending $count to my page. $count is the variable containing a MySQL query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($count[0]->{'COUNT(*)'} > 10) {
   ...
}
```

Note that `$count` looks very much like the result of an SQL query. In that case, simply replace  `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...` with `SELECT COUNT(*) AS foocount FROM ...`. Also, you can fetch into an array instead of an object.

Comment: You're right, it is the result of a SQL query. What is the difference between count(*) and count(*) AS foocount?

Comment: @Jonathan You can rename columns with `AS newname`, and this simply applies to columns generated by functions such as `count`, too. That would allow you to access the cells with the more natural `$count[0]->countfoo`, and you wouldn't need that curly-braces stuff.